# Display in f2 only terms related to selected term in f1

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, 9

I have a site that consists of a few parts like: Cosmos, Hi-tech, Travel, Music.

Each part has its own Categories. And I have made two Taxonomy vocabularies:

1. Part of a site
2. Categories (this has field 'Part of a site' and every category term has selected 'Part of a site' term)

Both Vocabularies are using in Node as Field 1, and Field 2.

But it is not convenient now to choose Cetegory term because categories from different Parts of a site are mixed and displayed all.

Can I manage these fields for set up 'Part of a site' first and then choose a Category from only those related to selected 'Part of a site' term?

Is there any solution for that on Drupal 9?

Comment: I found https://www.drupal.org/project/form_filter_fields but faced to an issue on Drupal 9.2.3: https://www.drupal.org/project/form_filter_fields/issues/3227411

Comment: Just use one single taxonomy with proper hierarchy.